# Ansible: Best practice to connect roles (meta, rolename: or import_role)

Tags: ansible, roles

There are three ways (as far as I know) to invoke another role:

1)  In a playbook with `role: rolename`

2)  In the role itself within the *rolename/meta/main.yml*-file with

```
dependencies:
  - { role: rolename2 }
```

3)

```
- import_role:
    name: anotherrolename
```

I guess I also know the differences: 
No. 2 (meta-methode) will *rolname2* execute before the things specified in tasks. 
No. 3 = https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/import_role_module.html

My question in the first place is not the difference between these methods (feel free to let us know) but I’d like to know what’s the best practice to connect two (or more) roles. Method 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because opinion based. Ask on devops.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fairly simple project where you want to mostly run the same roles in the same order on all nodes, go ahead and just call them in order in a playbook.

If you have a bit more complicated dependencies, and just want to manage roles dependent on each other, the meta dependencies method is fine, and as far as I know stable.

Unless you *need* the extra features from `import_role`, such as running a role multiple times with different parameters from within another task list, the metadata dependencies are to be preferred, because `import_role` is at the time of writing [in preview](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/import_role_module.html).

Answer (score 0):

Role "dependencies" *is* the defacto standard way to handle this.

See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-dependencies:

```
---
dependencies:
- role: wheel
  vars:
     n: 1
- role: wheel
  vars:
     n: 2
- role: wheel
  vars:
     n: 3
- role: wheel
  vars:
     n: 4
```

If you need a lower level of explanation please provide your particular use case(s).